# How can i export fbx with textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, .fbx

I've only been using blender for three months, so i dont know many things abt it n im trying to learn. But i got a job from lighting shop. I'm modelling lightings for my customer but they use 3ds max and they want everything in a .fbx. How can i export everytihng(model,textures,materials etc.) in a .fbx or another format? Is it possible? Thanks for helps :)

Btw my english is not well sorry for my language :)

Comment: I believe that you can just export your model as whichever format you want. Then open up your UVW window, load the texture into there, go to "Image> Save As" in that window and save it to the same location as the model you exported.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but let me ask u. U mean 3ds, should i save it in 3ds? Bcs i already export textures from blender n save it same location

Comment: I used 3DS Max for about 19 years but moved over to Blender recently. 3DS Max doesn't import Blender files. What I mean is export from Blender as .FBX and then, in the UVW space, save the textures as well into the same location that you saved the .FBX file. I know that .DAE automatically saves your textures in the same location as the .DAE file so that's also an option. FBX, DAE and .OBJ are the file formats most commonly used  for sharing models between software packages.